# bootstrap icon-angle-down not getting displayed on front-end

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Folks,
I have added bootstrap icon to one of my elements but it is not showing up.

Here is the code :

```
<span ng-repeat="element in header" class="header-cells" style="width:{{element.width}}px">
  <span>{{element.column}}
   <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
  </span>
</span>
```

the icon-angle-down does not show up.

The plnkr is here : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/MD8AsUSH0vrb2GlJORmv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you have used Bootstrap 3. Just check Documentation of latest version, the latest version doesn't support the "i" class for icons. Instead you have give as below.

```
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>
```

If you are using bootstrap 2. The code which have used will work perfectly.
Read the documentation of [Glyphicon](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons)